# JOLT concat values from nested array (Apache NiFi)

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

I have a JSON:

```
{
  "reports": [
    {
      "columnHeader": {
        "metricHeader": {
          "metricHeaderEntries": [
            {
              "name": "ga:sessions",
              "type": "INTEGER"
            },
            {
              "name": "ga:bounces",
              "type": "INTEGER"
            },
            {
              "name": "ga:sessionDuration",
              "type": "TIME"
            },
            {
              "name": "ga:pageviews",
              "type": "INTEGER"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "data": {
        "rows": [
          {
            "metrics": [
              {
                "values": [
                  "25",
                  "18",
                  "1269.0",
                  "27"
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ],
        "totals": [
          {
            "values": [
              "25",
              "18",
              "1269.0",
              "27"
            ]
          }
        ],
        "rowCount": 1,
        "minimums": [
          {
            "values": [
              "25",
              "18",
              "1269.0",
              "27"
            ]
          }
        ],
        "maximums": [
          {
            "values": [
              "25",
              "18",
              "1269.0",
              "27"
            ]
          }
        ],
        "isDataGolden": true
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

`metricHeaderEntries` and `values` for them are separated. Values are in `data.totals` array (order is saved correctly).
I want to modify JSON and get following structure (or similar to this, I only need pairs metric.name = metric.value):

```
{
  "metrics": [
            {
              "name": "ga:sessions",
              "value": "25"
            },
            {
              "name": "ga:bounces",
              "type": "18"
            },
            {
              "name": "ga:sessionDuration",
              "type": "1269.0"
            },
            {
              "name": "ga:pageviews",
              "type": "27"
            }
          ],
    "isDataGolden": true      
}
```

Is it possible with JOLT?
Before I only used `shift` spec for some very easy tasks. Following spec:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "reports": {
        "*": {
          "columnHeader": {
            "metricHeader": {
              "metricHeaderEntries": {
                "*": {
                  "name": "@(1,name)"
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "isDataGolden": "isDataGolden"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Returns:

```
{
  "ga:sessions" : "ga:sessions",
  "ga:bounces" : "ga:bounces",
  "ga:sessionDuration" : "ga:sessionDuration",
  "ga:pageviews" : "ga:pageviews"
}
```

"Almost". Not what i wanted of course. I need an array `metrics` with fields `name` and `value` as I described above. But I don't know how to get these values from `data.totals` and put them to metrics. And also `isDataGolden` disappeared. I read a little bit about `modify-overwrite-beta`, can i use it for my case?

Comment: what about script instead of jolt?

Comment: If it's not possible with JOLT or if it's hard to do with JOLT I'm okay with script. What kind of script?

Comment: how it should go if there are several elements under `reports` ?

Comment: U mean JOLT config for this scenario? I thought that if i couldn't solve it with JOLT, I just misunderstood smth. So, script should resolve this problem? What my script should to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use executegroovyscript

```
import groovy.json.*

def ff=session.get()
if(!ff)return

//read flow file content and parse it
def body = ff.read().withReader("UTF-8"){reader-> 
    new JsonSlurper().parse(reader) 
}

def rep0=body.reports[0]

def result = [ 
    metrics : rep0.columnHeader.metricHeader.metricHeaderEntries.indexed().collect{i,m->
            [ 
                name : m.name,
                value: rep0.data.totals[0].values[i]
            ]
        }, 
    isDataGolden : rep0.data.isDataGolden 
]

//write new flow file content
ff.write("UTF-8"){writer-> 
    new JsonBuilder(result).writeTo(writer) 
}
//transfer
REL_SUCCESS << ff
```

Comment: Many thanks! I guess for better experience with Apache NiFi i should start practice with Groovy. Because some uncommon things with NiFi are not easy to deal with.